# Points of failure in definition of X- and A-moduli spaces for arbitrary G

Tags: rt.representation-theory, gt.geometric-topology, lie-groups

In their work [0] on defining notions of higher Teichmüller space for local systems on surfaces, Fock and Goncharov require split reductive Lie groups, and sometimes also require simple-connectedness. What properties of these groups are required for the definition—in particular, what properties of Borel subgroups do Fock and Goncharov assume that, in general, do not hold for arbitrary Lie groups or algebraic groups?

[0] 
*Vladimir Fock and Alexander Goncharov*, MR 2233852 [**Moduli spaces of local systems and higher Teichmüller theory**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10240-006-0039-4), *Publ. Math. Inst. Hautes Études Sci.* (2006), no. 103, 1--211.